# Wordpress Child Theme CSS Import

Tags: css, wordpress, jigoshop

I am creating a Wordpress JigoShop Online Store. Having bought their Jigotheme, I have created a child theme and activated it (with Jigotheme as parent template).

I tried to import the styles from the jigotheme using:
@import url("../jigotheme/style.css");

(as per wordpress instructions)

The stylesheet is not pulling in - child theme works fine aside from this CSS import issue.

I know that no code can be above the @import code in the stylesheet - but would it not be working because the parent style.css also has @import code at the top of it? Are they conflicting perhaps?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an other `<link>`element to the head or [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) it.

Comment: The extra <link> would not work - as it would alter the parent theme. The Child Theme simply has a stylesheet in it, and pulls all other info from the Parent Template. I don't want to make any changes to the Parent theme in case of future updates to that theme. Thanks!

Comment: But `wp_enqueue_style()` would work in a `functions.php` in your child theme, without touching or overwriting anything from the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement should work. Double check the directory path and .css filename. If you're using Chrome, you can check the network tab to see if the parent style.css is actually being accessed.

Comment: Thanks Bonnie - I've tried putting a direct link, relative link, etc. None seem to work, but glad the code looks right for the import. I was just wondering if because the parent stylesheet also had import statements whether there could be a conflict. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow few steps:

1. Replace `bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` with `php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` (Credit goes to [@WouterB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332241/wouterb))
2. Check if your parent theme using stylesheet which is located under sub-folder (eg. theme/css/style.css), in this case you have to place your child theme css under that folder.
3. Remember to change path (may be you have to ../ before previous url)